# visual studio 2017 errors are not shown

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I'm using Visual studio 2017 Community v14.0.25431.01 Update 3 and errors are not shown. As you can see in VS 2015 i can see errors underlined but not in VS2017.

VS2017 Exemple :

[image: VS2017 exemple]

VS2015 Exemple :

[image: VS2015 exemple]

Comment: Do you have solution-wide analysis enabled in VS2017?

Comment: Yes it's enabled

Comment: Can you go to Help->About, click on the `Copy Info` button and paste in the first section here? That will have the exact version info for your build. I ask as VS 2017 maps to v15, and VS 2015 maps to v14. So I suspect you have a typo in your description of versions involved.

Comment: A have exactly same problem with large solution - no underline for errors.
When I create simple console application, the errors underlined fine.

My VS info is:
Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2017 
Version 15.3.3
VisualStudio.15.Release/15.3.3+26730.12
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.7.02053

Comment: Similar issue for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46592607/visual-studio-2017-not-highlighting-errors. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: i've uninstalled VS 2017 for instance. I'll re install it later I'll update this post after.

Comment: @ebelair any update? I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: No sorry i did not re installed VS2017. But you can give some information to @GusP

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't noticed the comments since my last response till @ebelair's last response produced a notification for me. Regardless, have any of you logged a feedback item through Visual Studio (icon in the top right of VS's window next to the Quick Launch box) on this? If so, please share the link here. I'll take a look and route it to the right team(s) to make sure it's on their radar. If anyone else is hitting the same problem, upvote items that match your experience.

Comment: @GusP thanks for helping, I just opened a feedback ticket: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/136196/errors-are-not-shown-in-code.html

Comment: @DennisSchröer: thanks. Will route to team.

Comment: @ebelair I noticed that this behaviour only happens in our company project, but not in a blank proect. I can't provide the project for testing, is this possible with your project? If so, could you provide it in this reported issue? https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/136196/errors-are-not-shown-in-code.html

Comment: After reinstalling VS 2017, the problem disapear

Answer (score 1):

You can try select `Build` instead of `Build+Intelisense`. It works for me.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Ok I also had that issue,
Found a solution that is quiet "barbare" but works perfectely ^^

The solution : 
**copy/paste all your cs files from the Solution explorer to the solution explorer.. It will automatically create : "nameOfYourComponent - Copy.cs"
Then you delete all the originals (the ones that are not named as "- Copy.cs")**

The exact copy are not running into that error anymore then.
I don't know why, but regenerating the files seems to fix it.

!!! Make sure you don't delete both files please :-/
At least if you have a repositery gitLab / gitHub, then is nice you can delete everything by mistake, everything is stored online.